# How can I correctly create a new file with org-roam-find-file?

Tags: org-mode

Somewhat new to emacs, org-mode, and org-roam, so I may be missing something here.  I installed org-roam from MELPA and included the 'use-package' section from [the documentation](https://org-roam.readthedocs.io/en/master/installation/) to my init file.

When I hit M-x and then type 'org-roam-find-file', I am prompted to enter the file name.  I enter the name of a file that does not exist and the minibuffer response is:

> Capture template 'd': Symbol's function definition is void: org-show-all

I tried entering the file name with and without the trailing '.org' and that didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: The error message indicates that Org mode has not been loaded: you should be able to solve that by adding `(require 'org)` somewhere in your init file.